# Music player volumeCtrl

Tags: java, swing, volume, javasound, jslider

Currently I am trying to control the volume of the track with JSlider. It shows no error, yet it is not adjusting the volume of track.

```
static final int VOLUME_MIN = 0;
static final int VOLUME_MAX = 6;
static final int VOLUME_INIT = 3;
static FloatControl gainControl;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSlider volumeCtrl = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, VOLUME_MIN, VOLUME_MAX, VOLUME_INIT);

    volumeCtrl.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JSlider source = (JSlider) e.getSource();
            if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                float volume = (float) source.getValue();
                float gain=1;
                float dB = (float) (Math.log(gain) / Math.log(10.0) * 20.0);
                if (volume == 0)
                    gainControl.setValue(0);

                gainControl.setValue(dB);
            }
        }

    });
    jf.add(volumeCtrl);
```

I expect it to adjust the volume of track with JSlider's knob.

Comment: The value of `dB` does not depend on the value of `volume` in any way:  `float dB = (float) (Math.log(gain) / Math.log(10.0) * 20.0);`

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hot link to a sound (small) file, or generate a tone / sound at run=time.